# How to get dimension and aspect ratio of input video and pass it as param to another input in the same command?

Tags: ffmpeg

I've a `mp4` file. I want to create an input color feed with same `dimension` and `sample aspect ratio`. Currently, I use `ffprobe` to get `dimension` and `sar` as a separate command and pass it to `ffmpeg` command manually.

> ffmpeg -y 
>       -i input.mp4 
>       -i bgm.mp3 
>       -f lavfi -i color=c=black:**s="1280"x"544":sar=1299/1280**:d=3.0 
>       -filter_complex ...

Is there any way to get `dimension` and `sar` of first input video to `-f lavfi -i color`.

Something like

> -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s="**widthOfFirstVideo**"x"**heightOfFirstVideo**":sar=**sarOfFirstVideo**:d=3.0

Answer (score 0):

The `scale2ref` filter makes size, SAR and DAR of input color feed the same as source video.

```
ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -f lavfi -i color=color=black \
-filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[1v][0v]\
,[0v][1v]overlay" \
-t 3 "input_color_feed.mp4"
```

Comment: Aspect ratio will be different: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=s=1280x720:sar=115/87:c=red -f lavfi -i color -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[black][red];[red]nullsink" -map "[black]" -frames:v 1 -f null -`

Comment: @llogan , with my parameters
`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=s=1280x720:sar=115/87:c=red -f lavfi -i color -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[1v][0v],[0v][1v]overlay" -frames:v 1 -f null -`
I get the correct output:
`1280x720 [SAR 115:87 DAR 1840:783]`

Comment: That's because you're using the reference video as the background for overlay.

Comment: OK, but the result will meet the OPs requirements

Comment: I believe theapache64 intends to concatenate instead of overlay so the aspect ratio difference is more of a concern.

Comment: I also assumed he would like to concatenate. I thought of `overlay` as an intermediate step. E.g. 2s black Intro + Movie: `ffmpeg -i "in.mp4" -f lavfi -i color=color=black -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[1v][0v],[0v][1v]overlay,trim=0:2[black];anullsrc,atrim=0:2[silent-audio];[black][silent-audio][0:v][0:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" out.mp4`